# How to make a look up table with negative indices/inputs in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, lookup, lookup-tables

I have a set of input matrices `A` with possibly negative elements. I also have a set of mappings from `int` to `int` which i wish to apply over `A` efficiently. 
Example:

```
import numpy as np

ind = np.array([-9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1])
out = np.array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9])

# i-th element of ind should return i-th element of out

a = np.array([[-1, -2, -3], [-4, -5, -6], [-7, -8, -9]])
# print(a)
# array([[-1, -2, -3],
#        [-4, -5, -6],
#        [-7, -8, -9]])

# i want output as 
# array([[ 9,  8,  7],
#        [ 6,  5,  4],
#        [ 3,  2,  1]])
```

Sorry if i couldn't put it precisely.
There need not be a function governing transformation from `ind` to `out`.

Only thing i could think of right now is making a dict and iterating over all elements of input matrix. But that would be slow. How to do this efficiently ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
In [43]: out[np.searchsorted(ind,a)]
Out[43]: 
array([[9, 8, 7],
       [6, 5, 4],
       [3, 2, 1]])
```

For a generic case when `ind` is not necessarily sorted, we need to use `sorter` arg -

```
In [44]: sidx = ind.argsort()

In [45]: out[sidx[np.searchsorted(ind,a,sorter=sidx)]]
Out[45]: 
array([[9, 8, 7],
       [6, 5, 4],
       [3, 2, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

### Another intuitive way:

`np.where(ind==a[x, y])[0][0]` returns the index in `ind` at which value `a[x,y]` is located.

```
>>> result = np.zeros(a.shape, dtype=np.int)

>>> for x in range(0, len(a[0])):  #rows
...     for y in range(0, len(a[1])):  #columns
...             indexInOut = np.where(ind==a[x, y])[0][0]
...             result[x,y] = out[indexInOut]
...
>>> result
array([[9, 8, 7],
       [6, 5, 4],
       [3, 2, 1]])
>>>
```